# Can't Connect to Hive using PyHive

Tags: python, hive, connection, pyhive

I'm having a problem connecting to `Hive` using `Pyhive`.

I'm using Virtualenv in a Windows machine (Win 10), I installed all the Pyhive's requirements (sasl, thrift, thrift-sasl and MS Visual C++ 9.0) but I got the same error...

> ```
> Wrong number of arguments for overloaded function 'Client_setAttr'.
>   Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
>     setAttr(saslwrapper::Client *,std::string const &,std::string const &)
>     setAttr(saslwrapper::Client *,std::string const &,uint32_t)
> ```

Here is my code:

```py
from pyhive import hive
print('Connecting at {}:{}/{}'.format(HOST_NAME, PORT, DATABASE))
hive_connector = hive.Connection(host=HOST_NAME, port=int(PORT), 
  database=DATABASE, auth='CUSTOM', username=USER, password=PASSWORD)
hive_cursor = hive_connector.cursor()
hive_cursor.execute('show tables')
```

And here is the packages installed in my virtual env

```py
future==0.17.1
pure-sasl==0.6.1
PyHive==0.6.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
"""I took sasl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
"""
sasl==0.1.3 
six==1.12.0
thrift==0.11.0
thrift-sasl==0.3.0
```

Could anyone help me? Apologies for the bad English.

Comment: I am assuming you are using `Python v2`?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Python 2.7